# One book being limited to max 3 courses | Sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, restriction

I want to limit one book to only be registered to 3 or less courses.  How would I create this restriction?  (Note I'm inexperienced and still learning)

```
CREATE TABLE Course (
Book       varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
Course     varchar2(50)
CONSTRAINT chk_Course CHECK (Course IN ('database', 'programming', 'mathematics', 'statistic', 'chemistry', 'physics')),
PRIMARY KEY(Book)
);
```

-

```
CREATE TABLE BOOK
(
    ISBN        VARCHAR2(50),
    TITEL       VARCHAR2(50),
    PUBLISHER   VARCHAR2(50),
    YEAR         DATE CHECK (YEAR between TO_DATE('1900/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') AND 
                                              TO_DATE('2017/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')),
    PRIMARY KEY(Isbn)
)
```

Comment: Varchar2(50) for an ISBN? That's generous! :)

Comment: Hah, totally slipped my mind!

Answer (score 0):

First, Course seems like an inappropriate name for that table. I think `book_assignments` or `books_courses` can be more accurate.

Second, in your current structure - a book can only be registered for one course, since `book` is a primary key in the Course table, which will only allow one row per book in that table. You will need to drop the primary key or change it to (Book,Course). Keep in mind that if the all of the tables' columns are in the primary key the design is probably not right.

One way to solve this problem is creating a trigger that queries the number of rows associated with the current book inserted, and failing the insert/update if the book is already registered to 3 courses.

I would choose a different approach, and use just one table for the books, with 3 columns called `course1,course2,course3`. This is not a very scalable solution if someday a book can be registered to say, 20 courses, but it's good enough for your homework.

Comment: The names were roughly translated from Norwegian, but yeah I agree on my poor translation of course.  So my easiest way to implement this is to just add 2 more colums?  This is also how the layed out the ER Schema of the task [Imgur link](http://imgur.com/a/foet3)   FagFelt = Courses Bok = Book

Comment: IF the assignment contained an ER you best stick to it, they probably want you to build it that way to teach you how to work with foreign keys

Comment: I wouldn't do the separate columns, but it is very difficult to enforce a restriction on the number of courses for a book. A trigger that maintains a NUMBER_OF_COURSES on the book table would work, but to be safe it would need to take a lock on the book row, and then check the current number of assignments, increment/decrement them, and then commit.

Comment: How would I create this trigger then?

Comment: That is a completely different question and probably a part of your homework. Read about Oracle triggers and the way their work, you'll probably figure it out.